# cin.ignore(INT_MAX) is clearing everything

Tags: c++, input, cin

I am trying to take input from a file which consist of an integer T, and T sentences following it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<limits.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    int m = 0;
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
    while(m < T) {
        string sentence;
        getline(cin,sentence,'\n');
        cout << "Case #" << m << ": " << sentence << endl;

        m++;
    }
}
```

On giving input of 5 strings, I am getting the following output.

```
Case #0: 
Case #1: 
Case #2: 
Case #3: 
Case #4:
```

This is file data

```
5
this is a test
foobar
all your base
class
pony along
```

Comment: Can you post an example of such a file? Anyway ignoring INT_MAX is discarding LOTS of characters from the standard input, I believe that isn't what you want

Comment: @MarcoA. I have added the contents of file.

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting to happen?

You tell the input stream to skip past billions of characters or until the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first:

```
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

Then you try to read from the stream again:

```
    getline(cin,sentence,'\n');
```

That fails because it's at EOF, but you don't check whether the read operation is successful.

Then after each failed read you print the empty string that wasn't changed because the read failed:

```
    cout << "Case #" << m << ": " << sentence << endl;
```

Then you repeat the attempt to read a line several more times.

Instead of just asking StackOverflow to fix your program, why don't you try to modify it to find out what's wrong?

e.g.

```
if (getline(cin,sentence,'\n'))
  cout << "Case #" << m << ": " << sentence << endl;
else
  throw std::runtime_error("getline failed");
```

Learning to isolate a problem in your code and identify where it misbehaves is an important skill that you will never learn by writing an entire program then turning to StackOverflow when it doesn't work.